# How to match a variable with the values inside of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a few locales inside and I want to check if the variable that returns the current locale, matches some of the locales inside the object.

This is my object:

```
var LocalesMapping = {
  'en_US': 'en-GB',
  'es_ES': 'es',
  'fr_FR': 'fr',
  'hu_HU': 'hu',
  'pt_BR': 'pt-BR',
  'pt_PT': 'pt-PT'
};
```

I tried to do it using `indexOf()`, but it returns `-1` when it matchs, instead of the other way around. This is how I did it:

```
if (Object.values(LocalesMapping).indexOf("'{{ app.request.locale }}'") > -1)
```

I believe `indexOf()` is for strings and arrays, not for objects, but I can't really find something useful for objects.

Comment: `"'{{ app.request.locale }}'"` looks odd to me. If i assume that the `{{...}}` part is some template that will get replaced with a value in pre-processing, I'm still left with `"'value'"` -- note that the value is in literal `'` quotes. My guess is that you want to remove the `'`s in that string literal.

Comment: It's also unclear whether you're looking for the *values* or the *keys*, and what kind of value `app.request.locale` may take.

Comment: I agree with @T.J. Crowder. And if this does not solve the issue, 
I guess you may mix up with Object.values() and Object.keys() ? To solve it easily, you may replace `"'{{ app.request.locale }}'"` with a string, like `fr`

Comment: `{{ app.request.locale }}` is because it's an angularjs variable inside a .twig and it will return, for exemple, `pt_BR` and that's why I want to match it with the object values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. `"'{{ app.request.locale }}'"` looks odd to me. If i assume that the `{{...}}` part is some template that will get replaced with a value in pre-processing, I'm still left with `"'value'"` -- note that the value is in literal `'` quotes. My guess is that you want to remove the `'`s in that string literal:

   ```
   if (Object.values(LocalesMapping).indexOf("{{ app.request.locale }}") > -1)
   ```

   Also note that you can use `includes` instead of `indexOf`:

   ```
   if (Object.values(LocalesMapping).includes("{{ app.request.locale }}"))
   ```
2. Both of the above will check the **values**, not the property keys. If you want to check for a matching property key, use `hasOwnProperty`:

   ```
   if (LocalesMapping.hasOwnProperty("{{ app.request.locale }}"))
   ```

---

Side note: In ES2015+ environments, you might consider using a Map instead of an object:

```
const LocalesMapping = new Map([
  ['en_US', 'en-GB'],
  ['es_ES', 'es'],
  ['fr_FR', 'fr'],
  ['hu_HU', 'hu'],
  ['pt_BR', 'pt-BR'],
  ['pt_PT', 'pt-PT'],
]);
```

Then a check for the *key* would be:

```
if (LocalesMapping.has("{{ app.request.locale }}"))
```

or a check for the *value* would be:

```
if ([...LocalesMapping.values()].includes("{{ app.request.locale }}"))
```

Comment: I guess I want to check the property keys after all, since using the ´hasOwnProperty()´ gives me the desired behavior! I'm sorry for the confusion and thank your for the clear explanation.